# Backward compatibility when adding an extra field to REST Spring web mvc JSON response best practice

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I've a simple bookstore REST Spring web mvc project:

```
public ResponseEntity<Book> getBook(@PathVariable("isbn") String isbn) {
    ... // return JSON response here wrapped into ResponseEntity
}
```

What is the best practice of adding an extra field into JSON response ( Book entity) and don't break old legacy clients who doesn't know about the new field?

Comment: adding information in your resource shouldn't break existing clients, as they won't need to deal with that information anyway. If there is something in your implementation that will break, then you can create for example, a new media type version, keeping the old one intact: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-versioning

Comment: Do you mean if a client accepts JSON response with 3 fields, there will not troubled him to send the same JSON with an extra field?

Comment: yes, if your JSON response is let's say {"bookId": String, "title": String} and suddenly your clients start getting {"bookid": String, "title": String, "author": String} that shouldn't be a problem. However if for some reason you do want to hide that from your clients or you changed/removed any field, you should consider versioning your API

Comment: Ok, thank you, how about remove a field? Will it troubled the client?

Comment: removing and changing (like renaming, changing types, etc) of your representation is normally a breaking change, because clients rely on that (see it as a contract).

Comment: Go with adding new api with version will be good idea as client  have not to worry about new field and in new api you can make any changes like,remove,change field.

Comment: Yes, but need to inform all clients altogether and they should apply the changes immediately which is not always possible

Comment: @J.J.Beam  did you reach a conclusion for your question? what did you do for the service?